# Why the size of the QList object is 4 bytes?

Tags: qt, sizeof, qlist

When trying to get the size of a `QList` object using `sizeof()`, function it gave me 4 bytes.
I tried to change the number of items in the list, it also gave 4 bytes?
I tried to change the type of the items in the list, again it gave 4 bytes?

Why the change in the number or type of items does not affect the object size?

Comment: Because it is just a pointer to the actual data, and a 32 bit pointer is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of items in the list, use the `QList::size()` not `sizeof()`. Something like this:

```
QList<MyObject> list;
list.append(object1);
list.append(object2);
int size = list.size();
```

`sizeof()` returns the size of the `QList` class, which is, as is often the case for Qt classes, made of only one member: a pointer to a private structure. Assuming you are on a 32bit OS, it takes 4 bytes to store an address, hence why you `sizeof(list)` returns 4.

Comment: after all this time, i think it is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` provides you with the compile-time size of the object itself, not of the data it may point to.

`QList` is a class containing a pointer to the data structure that actually holds a pointer to the heap-allocated data; of all this stuff, `sizeof` just knows (and cares) about that first bit - that `QList` contains just a pointer, hence it's 4 bytes big.

It's the exact same reason why if you do

```
int n;
std::cin>>n;
int *foo = new int[n];
std::cout<<sizeof(foo);
delete[] foo;
```

It'll always print 4 (or whatever the pointer size is on your machine), regardless of what `n` is set to.

Comment: Yes! this is c++